# Access to tables in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005, audit

I would like to know if there is a table where accesses to tables are saved, per user or per system.

I'm using both SQL Server 2005 and 2008.

Comment: You mean like an audit log for all select/update/insert/delete/...?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to find. And if there is anything `per user`.

Comment: Do you want to have permission information for all users that have access to your sql server ?

Answer (score 5):

The closest match to what you're looking for seems to be the [SQL Server Audit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd392015(v=sql.100).aspx) feature, which was added in SQL Server 2008 as a replacement/successor for [SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006(v=sql.105).aspx).

I recommend following the link to read up on it, since its setup/use is too big a topic to describe here in any meaningful way.

Comment: SQL Server Audit is availabe in the Enterprise Edition of SQL Server 2008 (and thus Developer and Enterprise Evaluation versions) and in the Standard Edition and higher of SQL Server 2012.

Answer (score 0):

Auditing insert, update, delete, and merge operations can also be done using DML triggers.

Answer (score -1):

Besides SQL Server Audit, there are some alternatives.

1. You can open SQL server Profiler to trace, but it will affect system
   performance.
2. Use 3rd party tool (e.g Quest LogReader) to read
   transaction log files.

Comment: No offense, but Profiler is a very bad idea for this. And I'm not sure what `SELECT` activity you expect to find in the transaction log...